Title: Extracting Tabular Data from Images Using Python and Tesseract OCR
I'm currently working on a project where I need to extract data in tabular format from images. The images contain data in a tabular format, and I need to save this data in a structured way for further processing.
I have written a Python script that uses Tesseract OCR to extract the text from the images. The script preprocesses the image, enhances the table structure, and then extracts the text using Tesseract OCR. Finally, it parses the extracted text into headers and rows and saves the structured data as JSON.
import cv2
import pytesseract
from PIL import Image
import tempfile
import shutil
import json

# Create a temporary directory for Tesseract's temporary files
tess_temp_dir = tempfile.mkdtemp()
os.environ["TMPDIR"] = tess_temp_dir
os.environ["TEMP"] = tess_temp_dir
os.environ["TMP"] = tess_temp_dir

# Set the Tesseract data path to the current script directory
temp_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)) + "/"
os.environ["TESSDATA_PREFIX"] = temp_dir

# Load and preprocess the image
image_path = '/Users/projects/data/testme.png'
image = cv2.imread(image_path)

# Convert to grayscale and apply adaptive thresholding
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
adaptive_thresh = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(gray, 255, cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C, cv2.THRESH_BINARY, 11, 2)

# Use morphological operations to enhance table structure
kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (2, 2))
morph = cv2.morphologyEx(adaptive_thresh, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel)

# Save the preprocessed image
preprocessed_image_path = '/Users/projects/data/preprocessed_image.png'
cv2.imwrite(preprocessed_image_path, morph)

# Re-open the image with the DPI setting for OCR
pil_image = Image.open(preprocessed_image_path)

# Define the PSM and OEM modes
psm_modes = [3, 6]
ocr_results = {}

for psm in psm_modes:
    custom_config = (
        r'-l deu --oem 3 --psm {} -c tessedit_char_whitelist="ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789-:.$%./@&*"'
    ).format(psm)
    try:
        text = pytesseract.image_to_string(pil_image, lang='deu', config=custom_config)
        ocr_results[psm] = text
    except pytesseract.TesseractError as e:
        ocr_results[psm] = str(e)

# Function to clean and parse the extracted text into a structured format
def parse_table(text):
    lines = text.split('\n')
    headers = []
    rows = []
    for line in lines:
        if line.strip():  # Skip empty lines
            # Assuming headers start with "Nr."
            if 'Nr.' in line and not headers:
                headers = line.split()
            else:
                rows.append(line.split())
    return headers, rows

structured_data = {}

for psm, text in ocr_results.items():
    if isinstance(text, str):
        headers, rows = parse_table(text)
        structured_data[psm] = {
            "headers": headers,
            "rows": rows
        }

# Save the structured data to a JSON file for review
json_results_path = '/Users/projects/data/ocr_results_structured.json'
with open(json_results_path, 'w') as json_file:
    json.dump(structured_data, json_file, indent=4)

# Print a summary of the results
for psm, data in structured_data.items():
    print(f"PSM Mode {psm} - Headers: {data['headers']}")
    for row in data['rows'][:5]:  # Print the first 5 rows for brevity
        print(row)

# Clean up the temporary directory
shutil.rmtree(tess_temp_dir)

Issues and Questions:
The OCR output is not always accurate, especially for complex table structures.
Parsing the OCR text into structured data is challenging.
anyone can show me what can be done to extract the data for this image.

